# Isotope appended broke remaining jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I have an instance of Isotope on my website that seems to have broken the remainder of my javascript functions after converting it to use the appended method. When I had all of my images were initially in the markup on my index.html, both isotope's filtering as well as a lightbox plugin I had for each image were working beautifully. Now I have implemented it as follows (using most of Desandro's code for Isotope:

HTML:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div id="filters" class="button-group">
            <p>FILTER:</p>
            <button class="selected" data-filter="*">SHOW ALL</button>
            <button class="" data-filter=".photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</button>
            <button class="" data-filter=".film">FILM</button>
            <button class="" data-filter=".design">DESIGN</button>
        </div>
        <div class="isotope">
            <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

var $container = $('.isotope');
$container.isotope({
    "itemSelector": ".item",
    "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer"
});

function getItemPhotography(i) {
    var item = '<div class="item photography"><a class = "fluidbox" href =        "img/photography/' + i + 'big.jpg" title = "Click to enlarge"><img src = "img/photography/' + i + '.jpg" class = "image"/></a></div >';
    return item;
}

function getItemDesign(i) {
    var item = '<div class="item design"><a class = "fluidbox" href = "img/design/' + i + 'big.png" title = "Click to enlarge"><img src = "img/design/' + i + '.png" class = "image"/></a></div >';
    return item;
}

var $items = getItems();
// hide by default
$items.hide();
// append to container
$container.append($items);
$items.imagesLoaded().progress(function(imgLoad, image) {
    // image is imagesLoaded class, not <img>
    // <img> is image.img
    var $item = $(image.img).parents('.item');
    $item.show();
    $container.isotope('appended', $item);
});

function getItems() {
    var items = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < 38; i++) {
        items += getItemPhotography(i);
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        items += getItemDesign(i);
    }
    // return jQuery object
    return $(items);
}

});
```

This part was broken after adding in the above:

```
//Filtering for isotope
$(function() {
$('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: filterValue
    });
});
$("button").click(function() {
    // Reset them
    $("button").removeClass("selected");
    // Add to the clicked one only
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
});

//Fluidbox lightbox plugin
$(function() {
    $('.fluidbox').fluidbox();
});
```

The images are appending to the Isotope container and laying out as expected. However, now filtering is broken for Isotope, and the Fluidbox lightbox instance is not working either.

Thanks so much for any help. I have been struggling with this for the past few hours and am starting to think it may be as simple as my function initializations or a semicolon somewhere.

Comment: Can you please break the code down to just the code you believe is related to the question?  This is a lot of code to work through ...

Comment: @rfornal sorry about that. fixed, removed some unnecessary code and broke it up. everything else I believe is relevant because all of the first section of Javascript is what broke the following two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Missing a reference for $container in the function for isotope filters.